# Blender Freezes every few minutes

Tags: error

Doesn't matter what you do in blender it freezes for 3-5 seconds every few minutes. The problem occurs in specific scenes (.blend files) on one specific PC. The problem can't be reproduced on other PCs (3 other PCs works well). Also blender doesn't freeze in empty or light (low poly) scenes.

rec of the screen (from 0:03): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxmaGSqJZaE

What should I check to figure out the cause of the problem?

specs:
intel i7 930, nvidia geforce gtx 960 (latest drivers), ram 8gb, win10 64x

Update: I checked the scene on another pc. Same lag. i5, rtx 2060, ram 16. So it should be not hardware related.

Comment: Of course it won't freeze in low poly scene! You've got a really heavy scene in your video, and since you don't have an extremely powerful machine, it is supposed to freeze until unless you make your scene more low-poly.

Comment: But I see no logic since it works well, let's say 3 minutes, no issues, and then something happens and it freezes. So, what could happen every 3 min?

Comment: What happens is that, at some point in the animation your computer gives up, and then after a lag it gets ok back again. This is right because your computer does not hang on low poly scenes.

Answer (score 2):

I solve that just deactivating the auto save feature in the save a loads panel preferences, after realize some test I notice that this happen on a new project without saving the file, just right after append a huge collection from another project, the freeze occurs every 2 minutes, the same time of the autosave...linking the collection don't cause the freeze problem, but I don't practice the linking workflow, so I solve killing the autosave on a huge .blend, now it's smoth! Hope that help, excuse my English!

Comment: thx! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was solved.
If the issue still exists after updating windows and nvidia driver, then this issue might just have to do with AUTOMATIC SAVE in blender, which occurs every two minutes by default, that's why my blender freeze frequently at every few moment(2 min)

So to solve this like I do, just disable automatic save or change the autosave time interval to be 20min or more. Whenever you SSD is nearly full and blender is loaded with too many plug-ins(in my case, I had over 5GB of plug-ins), the blender will freeze every time autosave takes place.

Hopefully, that's the case for the issue you are having right now.